# How can I tell if a move is special or physical?

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation

Special moves use Spc Atk, and Spc Def in their damage calculations.
Normal moves use Atk, and Def in their damage calculations.
How do I know which move is which?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you go to the move description, physical moves will have an orange and yellow "explosion" symbol, whereas special moves will have a purple "swirl" symbol in the same spot.

- Physical: [image: Physical]
- Special: [image: Special]
- Other: [image]

Images courtesy of [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/diamondpearl/battlechange.shtml).

As for moves your opponents' pokemon are using *against* you, you'll either have to look it up in an online database or wait until one of your own pokemon learns the move. There is no way to check that.

Comment: Whats 'Other' for? Moves such as growl or leer?

Comment: @Ender Exactly. All moves that don't deal damage directly are "Other".

Comment: They're usually called "Status" although that's not always an accurate term.